# AngularJS filter menu list with child

Tags: angularjs, filter, menu

Is it possible to use the angularjs default filter to filter out a side menu with children

Say for instance
[Filter input]

- Toyota

- - Corolla
- - Camry
- - Avalon
- - Sample

---

- Mercedez

- - c300
- - E300
- - CLS
- - MX
    ...

I want to be able to filter the menu and submenus , display anything than matches the filter regardless of the position
challenge
I'm calling ng-include for the template for each menu/submenu (link)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to manage menu items with a javascript array

```
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="filterStr">
    
     <ul class="nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-item" ng-repeat="item in ['Corolla', 'Camry'] 
                | filter: filterStr"><a href="#" class="nav-link">
                {{item}}</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

you may want to put menu items inside your controller and define a more expressive object with hrefs